# Swift - Using UIGestureRecognizer with UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var grayView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lightGrayView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var smileyFaceIMG: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func smileyMove(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        var point = sender.locationInView(view)
        smileyFaceIMG.center = point

        if CGRectContainsPoint(lightGrayView.frame, smileyFaceIMG.center) {
            smileyFaceIMG.image = UIImage(named: "Smiley_Face.jpg")
        }
    }
}
```

I have set up a `UIImage` which is supposed to change the image after I go over another `UIView`. This method seems to work with a regular `UIView`, however not with `UIImage`. How can I move the `UIImage` with the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: You want to change the location of the your `UIImage` or `UIImageView` in your `UIView`?

Comment: You need to know the translation and center of your recognizer view, then assign its value to be the center of your UIImageView, you can keep update the location of UIImageView while your UIGestureState is in Change

Answer (score 0):

I learned what my mistake was. I needed to create a regular UIView, and then drag the UIImgView onto it. Then replace the code from the UIImageView to the UIView. Now everything works properly.